# Selected Value not showing in Textfield Select - Material UI React Component

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, textfield, react-state

I have TextField Select Material UI components based on a certain number of value in a variable.

```
{this.state.selectedNextHops.map((nextHop, index) => (
              <div>
                <TextField
                    select
                    className="vnfprofile-field"
                    InputProps={{ className: 'variable-value site-details-view-textfield' }}
                    InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                    SelectProps={{
                        MenuProps: {
                            className: 'vnf-designer-value',
                            getContentAnchorEl: null,
                            anchorOrigin: {
                                vertical: 'bottom',
                                horizontal: 'left',
                            }
                        },
                    }}
                    value = {this.state.selectedNextHops[index] || ''}
                    disabled={this.props.newPopoverPanelView === 'VIEW' ? true : false}
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange('nexthop', e)}
                  >
                    {this.state.remainingNextHops.length !== 0 ? this.state.remainingNextHops.map((option, i) => (
                        <MenuItem key ={i} value = {option || ''}>
                          {option}
                        </MenuItem>
                      )) :
                        <MenuItem value = {'No Data Available'}>
                            {'No Data Available'}
                        </MenuItem>}
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField
                    className="vnfprofile-field subnet-textfield"
                    InputProps={{ className: 'variable-value' }}
                    InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                    value = {'29'}
                  />
                </div>
                ))
          }
```

The TextFields show up sequentially when I select value from the previous dropdown and filters the menu based on previous selection.

```
if(selectedNextHops.indexOf(event.target.value) === -1) {
            selectedNextHops.push(event.target.value);
        }
        remainingNextHops = this.props.nextHopSapds.filter(nextHop => selectedNextHops.indexOf(nextHop) === -1);

this.setState({
            selectedNextHops: selectedNextHops,
            remainingNextHops: remainingNextHops
        });
```

Update: Here is my handleChange Method ->

```
handleChange(type, event) {
    let selectedNextHops = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.selectedNextHops));
    let remainingNextHops = [];
    if(type === 'nexthop') {
        selectedNextHops = selectedNextHops.filter(nh => nh !== '');
        isContentChanged = true;
        if(selectedNextHops.indexOf(event.target.value) === -1) {
            selectedNextHops.push(event.target.value);
        }
        remainingNextHops = this.props.nextHopSapds.filter(nextHop => selectedNextHops.indexOf(nextHop) === -1);
        if(remainingNextHops.length !== 0) {
            selectedNextHops.push('');
        }
        this.setState({
            selectedNextHops: selectedNextHops,
            remainingNextHops: remainingNextHops
        });
    }
  }
```

The state is updating fine, but the textfield does not display the selected value. I have tried everything I knew. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share your `handleChange` method. Why is there a `value = {'29'}` prop?

Comment: I always want to show 29 in that field

Comment: A [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your issue would make it much easier to provide assistance.

Comment: @Katamari could you please create demo on Code Sandbox as suggested by Ryan. Otherwise it is really difficult to help you guys here.

Comment: @maximus https://codesandbox.io/embed/priceless-dijkstra-oqxzi I tried to boil both mine and OP's issue down to a simple version, value state is being set but not visible

Comment: @Katamari target values used to set state/select input are not correct. Check this corrected codesanbox demo https://codesandbox.io/s/great-lumiere-dgmyf You can fetch additional value per menu item using `event.currentTarget.dataset` in even handler.

Answer (score 5):

This is hard to debug without seeing a working snippet or the state ( especially `this.state.selectedNextHops`) , but based on the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/priceless-dijkstra-oqxzi) provided ( in the comment ) , I assume it's the same problem, so this answer will apply to the sandbox code :

```
this.setState({
  selectedID: event.target.value.id,
  visibleValue: event.target.value.name
});
```

`event.target.value.id` and `event.target.value.name` are `undefined`,

```
console.log(console.log(event.target)) // {value: "S0002", name: undefined}
```

For the `select` to display a selected `option`, the `value` attribute for both need to match :

```
<select value="2">
        ^^^^^^^^^
  <option value="1">first value</option>
  <option value="2">second value</option>
          ^^^^^^^^^ 
</select>
```

in the example in the code sandbox, the value of the `Select` is `value={this.state.visibleValue}` and the values of the options are `value={x.label}`

Since `this.state.visibleValue` is always `undefined`, you'll never see the value of the `select` update.

A quick fix for this is to change the `handleChage` function to :

```
handleChangeTest = event => {
  this.setState({
    selectedID: event.target.id,
    visibleValue: event.target.value
  });
};
```

but that will leave `selectedID` undefined , to set it, add the attribute `id={x.id}` to the `option` and use `event.currentTarget` to get its value :

```
{this.state.data.map(x => (
  <MenuItem key={x.id} value={x.label} id={x.id}>
                                      ^^^^^^^^^
    {x.name}
  </MenuItem>
))}
```

And

```
handleChangeTest = event => {    
  this.setState({
    selectedID: event.currentTarget.id,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    visibleValue: event.target.value
  });
};
```

[Working SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-morning-vl0e6)

Answer (score 3):

So you try to access the key with e.target.value.id but the target object has only the value and not the id itself. That is why it is undefined after you call the handleChange method. There is a way to access the key though:

The callback does not only pass the event but also the child object as second parameter and this can be used to get the key like this:

```
handleChangeTest = (event, child) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedID: child.key,
      visibleValue: event.target.value
    });
  };
```

This will set the key as selectedID and the value of the selected item as visibleValue.